# Loop through values in a column and put them into categories in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this column `edu` has values from 0-20 (the first value is 13, the first column is index), I want to loop through each value in the "edu" column and assign them into categories.

```
age work    edu marry   occup   race    sex country
0   39  4   13  6   10  0   0   0
1   50  1   13  0   0   0   0   0
2   38  5   9   3   6   0   0   0
3   53  5   7   0   6   1   0   0
4   28  5   13  0   1   1   1   2
5   37  5   14  0   0   0   1   0
6   49  5   5   4   7   1   1   8
```

I want to generalize it into 3 levels. But what I wrote doesn't work and I am not sure how to approach it.

```
edu_cat=[]
for index, row in adult_num1[['edu']].iterrows():
    if row <= 12:
         edu_cat.append("some education")
    elif 13 < row < 17:
        edu_cat.append("college education")
    elif  17 < row < 21:              
        edu_cat.append("graduate education")
return edu_cat
```

I plan to apply a similar idea to other columns as well. How should I do that? I am new to python.

Comment: `pd.cut`: `pd.cut(df.edu, [0, 12, 17, 21], labels=['some education', 'college education', 'graduate education'])`.

Comment: Note that when you have a problem like this, it is a good idea to provide the code to generate the dataframe that you're working with so users have a test example to work with.

Comment: Thank you so much@P! That makes so much sense now! And I will remember to include the data frame code for the future @Kraigolas.